# Multiple Variants with Theme-UI

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I am trying to learn how to use [Theme-UI](https://theme-ui.com/) (which is made by the same person who made [Styled-System](https://styled-system.com) and [Rebass](https://rebassjs.org)).  Like in Styled-System (and Rebass) there is a theme file which has the option for creating variants (see here for details:  https://theme-ui.com/theme-spec/#variants).

So, for example, I can create different styled buttons -- like this:

```
buttons: {
    primary: {
      // you can reference other values defined in the theme
      color: 'white',
      bg: 'primary',
    },
    secondary: {
      color: 'text',
      bg: 'secondary',
    },
  }
```

I can then use those variants as follows:

```
<button
  sx={{
    variant: 'buttons.primary',
  }}>
```

The problem is, I want to be able to create multiple variants for buttons.  For example, let's say I want to have the following three variants:

1. Size (small, medium, large, etc).
2. Look (primary, secondary, disabled, etc).
3. Kind (default, outline, text, etc).

So that I could style a button like this:

```
<button
 sx={{
    size="buttons.size.large"
    kind="buttons.kind.outline"
    look="buttons.look.secondary"
 }}
/>
```

This IS possible with style system -- here is an example:

- https://mathanpec.github.io/component-library/?path=/story/button--size-variant
- https://github.com/mathanpec/component-library/blob/basic-setup/src/theme/buttonStyle.ts

But I can't figure out how to do with with Theme-UI.

Does anyone know how to do this with Theme-UI?

Comment: do not use it. it is depricated

Comment: What is depricated?  Theme-UI?  It's last commit was 2 days ago and the latest release was 19 days ago.  And styled-system last commit was 4 days ago and it's latest release was 20 days ago.